# Jquery UI datepicker rotates on selection when number of months shown are more than one

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

If 2 months are shown using Jquery UI datepicker for both depart & return date e.g. March, April & if depart date is selected as in March while return date in April then when again clicked on Return Date Calender shows April, May instead of March, April as calender rotates to the current selection of return date. I need to disable this calender movement in case of return.

Tried onChangeMonthYear but it is reached post _updateDatepicker is called and did not help.

Also tried showCurrentAtPos but this renders another calender on top of existing one and did not help either.

Comment: i'm aware this isn't what you are asking, but maybe you'll find it nice to try: https://plnkr.co/edit/gJnaZT2QHPBUtRgVFv3s?p=preview

Comment: I am looking for something like airbnb datepicker where calender is shown wrt. departure date and not wrt. return date even if they are in far different months.
It seems they have used react datepicker.
Just wanted to know if same can be achieved using Jquery UI date picker.